# Extracting jpeg from POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, jpeg

How can I extract a jpeg from a POST request into a file? The POST request header is NOT `MimeMultipartContent` :( which all the examples on the web appear to show. `this.Request.Content.Headers.Contenttype.MediaType` contains the string `image/jpeg` and 
`Debug.Trace(this.Request.Content)` just gives me `"System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+LazyStreamContent"`

Here is my code so far:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post()
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
    Trace.WriteLine(request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);  // "image/jpeg"

    // Do the extraction to a file here

    return Ok("Worked");
}
```

Comment: extract the content stream `var imageStream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` from there you can do what you want with the stream.

Comment: For reference: I was trying to write a C# equivalent of the perl cgi script at https://www.axis.com/gb/en/support/technical-notes/upload-images-video-to-http-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the content stream from the request. From there you can do what you want with the stream.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post() {
    var request = this.Request;
    Trace.WriteLine(request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);  // "image/jpeg"

    var imageStream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    //...save stream to disk or database...etc.    

    return Ok("Worked");
}
```

Comment: Superb! Thanks
For anyone else's reference to save to disk you can use:
    using (var FileStream = File.Create(destination))
    {
        ImageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 ImageStream.CopyTo(FileStream);
    }